# Locating data in a complex table in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-table

I am currently trying to drill down on a user in a table full of users using Selenium webdriver, I have worked out how to iterate through the table but I'm having trouble actually selecting the person I want.

Here is the HTML  (modified with X's due to it not being my data)

```
<table id="XXXXXXXXX_list" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style=" border:0px black solid;WIDTH:100%;">
<tbody>
<tr cellspacing="0" style="height: 16px;">
<tr>
<tr onclick="widgetListView_onClick('XXXX_list',1,this,event)">
<tr onclick="widgetListView_onClick('XXXX_list',2,this,event)">
<tr onclick="widgetListView_onClick('XXXX_list',3,this,event)">
<tr onclick="widgetListView_onClick('XXXX_list',4,this,event)">
<tr onclick="widgetListView_onClick('XXXX_list',5,this,event)">
<tr onclick="widgetListView_onClick('XXXX_list',6,this,event)">
<tr onclick="widgetListView_onClick('XXXX_list',7,this,event)">
<td class="listView_default_dataStyle" nowrap="" style="font-size:12px ;
font-family: sans-serif ;color: black ;background: #FFFFFF " 
ondblclick="XXXXListView_onDblClick('XXXXX_list',17, event)">NAME</td>
<td class="listView_default_dataStyle" nowrap="" style="font-size:12px ;font-family: sans-serif;
color: black ;background: #FFFFFF " ondblclick="XXXXX_onDblClick('XXXX_list',17, event)"> </td>
</tr>
```

Here is the code I am writing to try and find the user going by NAME in the table.

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("table_list"));

    // Now get all the TR elements from the table
    List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    // And iterate over them, getting the cells
    for (WebElement row : allRows) {
     List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
     for (WebElement cell : cells) {         
        List<WebElement> Names = cell.findElements(By.xpath("//td[text()='NAME']"));
        System.out.println(Names);
```

This just prints thousands of []  (the table is huge in the real application).
Essentially what I need is to stop when I find the correct name and create a web element out of that table row. Which I can then click and drill down on.

Sorry if any of this is a bit vague,

Comment: If it isn't clear from the HTML, the 2 <td> tags are from the 17th <tr> tag, not that I think that is hugely relevant

Comment: So you want only 1 element with text 'Name' and then you want to look further into it?? Or do you want all elements with text Name and drill into each of these??

Comment: Moreover, why are you printing the list **Names**??

Comment: Essentially the table is a list of people, I need to select a person based on their name and then select that table row and then be able to .click it.  
I'm just really confused. Maybe everything I've done for this table is the wrong approach. All I know is there is no attribute = name, it's just sort of floating there in the <td>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if each name in the table is unique, you don't need to complicate things so much. Just search for element with text matching your 'Name' then select the row accordingly. Look at the code below:

```
WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='XXXXXXXXX_list']//td[contains(text(),'NAME')]"));//Select td with text NAME in table with id XXXXXXXXX_list
WebElement rowWithName = name.findElement(By.xpath("./.."));//Select the parent node, i.e., tr, of the td with text NAME
/*
 * Look into that row for other element or perform any action on the row.
 */
```

If the names are not unique, i.e., same name exists twice at similar node, 1st instance will be picked each time. In that case we will have to try things differently, i.e., we will have to index the xpath for correct instance of matching name. Do ask if you have any further doubts :)

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation here and below.  Unfortunately this isn't working for me. I just get an unable to locate element. I changed the XXXXX_list to be the table ID and put a segment of the student name in the [text()='Adams']".  Is the problem possibly that I have no reference to the tr's.  I select the table, then go straigh into looking at //td without first navigating through the tr's?   I'm just guessing, I'm sure you'll know more.

Thank you

Comment: Well what do you mean by _'segment of student name'_? If it is not the exact text in tr, it will not be found. In that case we will have to use contains. Look at the modified code above. And no, what you guessed is not a problem because we are using **//** before td, which allows the td tag to be searched anywhere in table, irrespective of where it is (inside tr in our case).

Comment: Gah this is driving me crazy. With this new code I'm getting an error on the second line :\   ... Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/.."}  I'm sorry if this is getting annoying

Comment: Try again you should not get any error. The error was occurring because whole page was searched for /.. now I have added . before the 2nd xpath. So it will look for 2nd xpath from current (td) node.

Comment: Thank you!!  Finally working. However I am putting in find "Adams Owen" and it is finding "Adams Melanie" but that's a different issue, If I can't figure that one out I'll make a different question. :) Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

This will help you out.

```
     try{
ArrayList<WebElement> cells = (ArrayList<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
log4j.info("Value = "+input_type+" is stored in array from Webpage for "+keyword+" ");
for(WebElement type : cells)
{
    if(type.getAttribute("name").equals("your correct name here")) {

        type.sendKeys("ABC");

    }
}
return true;
}catch(Throwable e){
    return false;
}
```

You need to use Array list like this and you can compare your Name in which you wanna fill value Or wanna do any operation like getText(), click() etc.

Enjoy!

Comment: Hi, I'm still quite new at this and honestly this just confused me. I am not using log4j, so is that line needed?  Also if you check the HTML I'm not sure what attribute to put in the type.getAttribute() because the name is just sort of floating in the ether.

Comment: avoid log4g if you are not using, and name is the attribute of a input tag field and you have to write here--> ("your correct name here") what you wanna compare i mean in which field you want to perform any operation then , use the functions accordingly, Same case in Table you can use By class with tag name.

Comment: <td class="listView_default_dataStyle" nowrap="" style="font-size:12px ;font-family: sans-serif ;color: black ;background: #FFFFFF " ondblclick="widgetListView_onDblClick('student_list',3, event)">Billy Claire (22) </td>
Thanks for the quick reply, what is confusing me at the moment is the information I want is the 'Billy Claire'  bit at the end. I just can't figure out a way to select that.  Currently I keep printing really strange data. I'll post what I am currently getting from printing in a comment below

Comment: [[[[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on XP (614c41fc-244f-4f72-9f5e-c6dbffa8d2d5)] -> id: tablestudent_list]] -> tag name: tr]] -> tag name: td], [[[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on XP (614c41fc-244f-4f72-9f5e-c6dbffa8d2d5)] -> id: tablestudent_list]] -> tag name: tr]] -> tag name: td]]

Comment: Wow you really a newbie. No probs :). You are getting this data because you are printing a **List** object, which I had questioned earlier. println() method prints only String objects, which in your case is the description of that list object. Moreover I don't know what Himanshu is trying to tell. Either he did not understand your problem, or I did not understand his solution (which I doubt).